# HTML Tables with lots of CSS

Tags: html, css

I am building advanced HTML tables with lots of CSS in them, what are the best tools out there for building advanced HTML CSS tables that could include dynamic elements like AJAX driven features (jQuery). I use Dreamweaver and Eclipse but they just touch the surface of having a really great tool set to build with. If you use a great tool let me know about it:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, the closer to the metal you get, the better off you'll be. On the Mac, I use TextMate for doing the HTML and Javascript, and CSSEdit for editing the CSS.

Comment: Komodo Edit is also worth a look, it is my editor of choice on just about any OS platform.

Answer (score 2):

Best tool ever, either Textpad or Notepad++. 
Both support syntax highlighting for a variety of languages, tabbed interface, etc.
Stay away from frontpage / dreamweaver.

Also if I may ask, why as you making HTML tables, I am hoping not for a layout?

Answer (score 2):

I'll second Notepad++.  How about an Express edition of Visual Studio 200x?  You get some great design tools, great syntax highlighting, and it's free.

Comment: It's a hefty install just for a text-editing framework, that is my only concern about the express vs. Good one though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good free Mac editor, I go with WordWrangler. But if you want something that will cover EVERYTHING for web design, go with Coda.

For PC, I use notepad++. Not as slick as the ones for Mac, but it does allow for editing straight from the server.

But as far as CSS for tables specifically, you are going to want to do as much of it on your own, as tables are the worst when it comes to accessibility and semantic mark up, and that can only be dealt with by hand. Things like scope, colgroups, etc are never going to be WYSIWYG, you have to fine tune it.

Here's a good starting point:

http://www.noupe.com/css/21-fresh-ajax-css-tables.html